# Cooling effect of sipping

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Is the primary action of cooling of a sipped hot fluid explained by the reduced flow of the hot fluid, the air cooling of the fluid as it is sipped or another factor?

Comment: Why do you assume we sip in order to cool the liquid? I think we sip more to lessen the amount of hot liquid that could burn our mouths in the case that it is too hot. But mixing cold air with the liquid in the sipping process would reduce the heat quite a bit

Comment: I'm not assuming everyone sips to cool. My question is just narrowly interested in that particular scenario.

Comment: My apologies then. Carry on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all of them. You have reduced amount due to aeration (bubbles), cooling via convection and cooling via conduction into the side of the cup/bowl.